# Perl - How does sort happen?

Tags: perl, sorting

I have just started learning Perl. I was trying out some functions in Perl and came across the sort function. It worked fine with a set of input, but for a different input there was a different and unexpected result.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use List::MoreUtils qw/ uniq /;

my @faculty = sort(1231,444,444,444,1232);

my @unique = uniq @faculty;
foreach ( @unique ) {
    print $_, "\n";
}

my @array1 = sort(3,3331,32,3);
my @array = uniq @array1;

print "My array = @array\n";
```

This is a sample script I wrote. The output for this is:

> 1231 1231 444 My array is 3 32 3331.

Why is 444 not sorted?

Comment: "Why is 444 not sorted?" In `@unique`, it is. In `@array1`, because it wasn't in it in the first place.

Comment: @Amadan - The output for array1 is 3 32 3331 as expected. But for unique the output is 1231 1232 444 instead of 444 1231 1232. Why is 444 the first result?

Comment: As @sotcha says, `444` is after `1232` just like `bee` is after `aardvark`.

Comment: Yeah ! Got it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sorted as a character not as a number.

Try

```
my @faculty = sort {$a<=>$b} (1231,444,444,444,1232);
```

The output is :

444
1231
1232

You can check : 
[sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)

Comment: Means sort numerically ascending, otherwise {$b <=> $a}  means descending

Comment: @abc : Sorting is done by using special variables in perl and hence the values are stored in $a and $b by default.

Answer (score 2):

Perl's `sort` routine sorts in alphabetical order by default.  Therefore 1231 comes before 444.

To sort in numerical order, use the `sort` routine with the numeric comparison operator:

```
my @faculty = sort { $a <=> $b } (1231, 444, 444, 444, 1232);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is done as string be default so "1" is before "4" in string space, so 1234 will be less then 444. If you had 1, 2, 4, 10; the sorted order would 1,10,2,4;

If you want to sort them numerically (as numbers), then you need to supply block or routine to do the sorting. For example, you can use <=> for numeric comparison in a block with sort.

```
 my @faculty = sort { $a <=> $b } (1231,444,444,444,1232);
```

which will output 444, 1231, 1232.